# Automated GUI Testing for Qt WebKit application

Tags: qt, selenium, webkit, automated-tests, qtwebkit

I'm writing a Qt application that uses a QWebView to host the UI. Similar to the ImageAnalyzer example in the Qt SDK samples.

I would like to test this UI using an automated method. A scripting interface like Selenium Web-Driver would be preferable.

Any recommendations/examples on how to do this?

**Edit:**

I'm looking for a solution can identify HTML elements via classes and id's so that it's maintainable and robust to change.

Tools like Sikuli (which are appearance based), don't satisfy this criterion. Note: I believe those are great for quick one-off scripting, they just don't work very well across many different platforms/configurations and over time for my purpose.

Comment: Have you tried the sikuli (http://sikuli.org/)?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't quite serve my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure this would satisfy your *"Qt application that uses a QWebView"* requirement, but when you say *"I'm looking for a solution can identify HTML elements via classes and id's so that it's maintainable and robust to change."* I can think of [WatiR](http://watir.com/) (which is a "browser driver").
It's open source so perhaps you could adapt it to drive your application.

There is also a .Net version called [WatiN](http://watin.org/), but then you are restricted to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WebDriver implementationfor Qt: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver

Using Selenium tests and this WebDriver you can automate QtWebkit, widget and QML applications